# How to do conditional check in typescript base on an object's key value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type an object that looks like:

```
{
  entrées: [{ id: '1', 'name': 'a' }],
  plats: [{ id: '2', 'name': 'b' }],
  accompagnements: [{ id: '3', 'name': 'c' }],
  menu: [{ id: '4', config: [...] }]
}
```

with type:

```
type MockData = {
  [key: string]: key extends 'menu' ? MenuEntry[] : CommonEntry[];
};
```

But it ends up with error:

> key  refers to a value, but is being used as a type here

How can i correctly use the object key for condition check?
I will be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: There is unfortunately no specific type in TypeScript that works this way; you can't properly express "`string` but not `"menu"` as a type.  There are various workarounds that satisfy some use cases but they are not perfect. See the question linked above and its answers for more detailed information.  Also see the feature request at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867)